# How to store Date and Time input type from html form into sqlite3 DB

Tags: html, go, sqlite

I am setting up a `reminder` feature in a personal assistant application. The application accepts the details of the reminder as a html form which also include `date` and `time` input fields.

I am using golang for creating my server and created a sqlite database using it. But the value of date and time from the form doesn't get saved in the DB while other fields like title, description, etc gets saved. What datatype should I use for my time and date fields in the sqlite DB?

I have tried using `TEXT` as the datatype for date and time but it doesn't work.

Input form:

```
   ...
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="date">Date</label>
   <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" data-ng-model="formData.remDate" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label for="time">Time</label>
   <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" data-ng-model="formData.remTime" required>
</div>
   ...
```

This is the `reminder object` that is generated from the form:

```
{title: "learn golang", description: "How do I save date and time in database?", date: Mon Apr 08 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), time: Thu Jan 01 1970 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
```

Golang file for creating and storing in DB:

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type reminder struct {
    id int
    title string
    description string
    date string
    time string
}

func ReminderController(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    r.ParseForm()

    request := reminder{
        title: r.FormValue("title"),
        description: r.FormValue("description"),
        date: r.FormValue("date"),
        time: r.FormValue("time"),
    }
    fmt.Println(request)

    AddReminder(request, w)

}

func prepareDB() {
    database, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./jarvis.db")
    checkErr(err)

    statement, err := database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reminder (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT")
    checkErr(err)

    statement.Exec()
}

func AddReminder(reminderObject reminder,  res http.ResponseWriter) {
    prepareDB()

    database, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./jarvis.db")
    checkErr(err)

    statement, err := database.Prepare("INSERT INTO reminder (title, description, date, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ")
    checkErr(err)
    fmt.Println(reminderObject.title)
    statement.Exec(reminderObject.title, reminderObject.description, reminderObject.date, reminderObject.time)

    ShowReminder()

    res.Write([]byte(`{"status": "success", "message": "Reminder has been set !"}`))
}

func ShowReminder() {
    prepareDB()

    database, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./jarvis.db")
    checkErr(err)

    rows, err := database.Query("SELECT id, title, description, date, time FROM reminder")
    checkErr(err)

    var id int
    var title string
    var description string
    var date string
    var time string

    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&id, &title, &description, &date, &time)
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(id) + ": " + title + " " + description + "\nEnd Time : " + date + ":" + time)
    }
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Output generated in go console :

```
3: learn golang How do I save date and time in database?
End Time : :
```

Comment: In `AddReminder`, `statement.Exec` returns an error but you're ignoring it. Check that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer type in sqlite table and your time property in reminder struct should change to time.Time

```
type reminder struct {
    id int
    title string
    description string
    date string
    time time.Time
}
```

In order to convert your form date and time strings into a time.Time format you should parse your strings like so :

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
str := fmt.Sprintf("%sT%sZ", r.FormValue("date") , r.FormValue("time"))
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
```